# Glide (bitmapTransform) - Can't get context

Tags: android, android-glide

I have problem with using glide-bitmapTransform
Every time, I try using bitmapTransform, the RedLine came below context.
It doesn't matter BlurTransformation, CropCircleTransformation, GrayscaleTransformation, or others.

Here is my Code

```
  Glide.with(mcontext)
                    .load(R.drawable.img)
                    .bitmapTransform(new BlurTransformation(mcontext,8))
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                    .skipMemoryCache(true)
                    .into(iv);
```

.bitmapTransform(new BlurTransformation(mcontext,8)) <- that context is my problem.
I try to turn context into this, getApplicationContext(), getApplication(), or ActivityName.this. but it is useless.
Please help me on this what wrong I've done here.
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but your question is not clear.
Are you sure you have added BlurTransformationClass.java in your project?
I don't  think so context is your problem.

You can find BlurTransformationClass here

https://github.com/wasabeef/glide-transformations/blob/master/transformations/src/main/java/jp/wasabeef/glide/transformations/BlurTransformation.java

```
Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.demo)
    .bitmapTransform(new BlurTransformation(context,25))
    .into((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image));
```

If problem still not solve than please tell us what error that red line showing.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I checked my version of Glide-transformation. And I realized I  compile 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:1.0.6@aar' instead of compile 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:2.0.1'
The problem has been solved!! Thaks you

Answer (score 0):

firstly make sure about activity,fragment and adapter.

for example:
1.if you use Glide in activity then put MainActivity.this or this:

```
Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(R.drawable.pic)
.bitmapTransform(new BlurTransformation(context,25))
.into((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagePic));
```

2.if you use Glide in fragment then put getActivity() :

```
Glide.with(getActivity).load(R.drawable.pic)
.bitmapTransform(new BlurTransformation(context,25))
.into((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagePic));
```

3.if you use Glide in adapter then put context:

```
Glide.with(mContext).load(R.drawable.pic)
.bitmapTransform(new BlurTransformation(context,25))
.into((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagePic));
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly make sure about activity, fragment and adapter.

For example: If you use Glide in activity then put `MainActivity.this` or this:

```
Transform(new BlurTransformation(context,25))
```